# Only Perform Group By When Combo Box is Not Empty

Tags: sql, ms-access, iif-function

I've solved this problem before. Unfortunately, I'm having the hardest time remembering my solution.

I have three combo boxes, one of which (Quarter) the user can choose to leave empty. All three combo boxes are attached to fields in a query. Each field is setup to perform a Group By (Case Manager, Fiscal Year, Quarter). If the combo box for Quarter is not empty, the query filters correctly. It performs a Group By for Case Manager, Fiscal Year, and Quarter.

When the combo box for Quarter is left empty, the query should only Group By Case Manager and Fiscal Year. Currently it performs a Group By on Quarter as well.

This is the SQL for the query:

```
SELECT tblCM.CM, tblFY.FiscalYear, tblQtr.Quarter, Count(tblData.CaseNum) AS CountOfCaseNum,
Avg(tblData.[DaysToNotifySite-CompleteCalc]) AS [AvgOfDaysToNotifySite-CompleteCalc],
Avg(tblData.[Days to Contact Site]) AS [AvgOfDays to Contact Site],
Avg(tblData.DaysToHoldMedAfterOrder) AS AvgOfDaysToHoldMedAfterOrder,
Avg(tblData.DaysToHoldMed) AS AvgOfDaysToHoldMed,
Avg(tblData.DaysToIssueDGODec) AS AvgOfDaysToIssueDGODec,
Avg(tblData.DaysToCloseAfterDecRecdByNRC) AS AvgOfDaysToCloseAfterDecRecdByNRC,
Avg(tblData.DaysToCloseCase) AS AvgOfDaysToCloseCase

FROM tblQtr INNER JOIN (tblFY INNER JOIN (tblCM INNER JOIN tblData ON  tblCM.CM = tblData.[CMNames-Corrected])
ON tblFY.FiscalYear = tblData.FiscalYearFilingForm) ON tblQtr.Quarter =  tblData.QtrFilingFormRec

WHERE (((tblData.Type)<>"DRA"))

GROUP BY tblCM.CM, tblFY.FiscalYear, tblQtr.Quarter

HAVING (((tblCM.CM)<>"Doe, John" And (tblCM.CM)=[Forms]! [frmIndividualGoals]![cboCM])
AND ((tblFY.FiscalYear)=[Forms]![frmIndividualGoals]![cboFY])
AND ((tblQtr.Quarter)=IIf([Forms]![frmIndividualGoals]![cboQtr]<>'',[Forms]![frmIndividualGoals]![cboQtr])))
OR (((tblCM.CM)<>"Doe, John" And (tblCM.CM)=[Forms]![frmIndividualGoals]![cboCM])
AND ((tblFY.FiscalYear)=[Forms]![frmIndividualGoals]![cboFY])
AND (([Forms]![frmIndividualGoals]![cboQtr]) Is Null));
```

The SELECT statement is fine. I certainly may be wrong. But, I believe that my problem is in the last AND statement. But, I provided all of my SQL for reference.

Currently I'm just using a command button to open the query after selections are made in the combo boxes to test the results.

Thank you for any help that anyone can provide.

Comment: I NEVER use dynamic parameterized queries. I prefer VBA to construct WHERE CONDITION of OpenForm/OpenReport or to set form Filter property. Why are you opening a query and not a form or report bound to query? The IIf() does not have value to return if condition is false. Have code in the button click event to make sure comboboxes have data before opening query.

Comment: It's okay if the Quarter combo box doesn't have data. Only the Case Manager and Fiscal Year combo boxes are required...Right now, I'm only testing for the solution I had last week, until an ill-timed computer restart occurred....Opening a query, binding it to form or report doesn't change what the solution would be. I'll tidy things up when I move past this point.

Comment: The query worked before? I still would not use dynamic parameterized query. Sorry, if fixing the IIf() does not resolve, reason for failure escapes me.